# Error when entering table_array with spaces in the name Excel Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

first my apologies for being a noob with regard to Excel Formulas - I did  search and did not find an answer.

I have a spreadsheet that I am trying to modify.  I got two spreadsheets from a client, who gave me a working copy and one that he had modified.  There is a #REF error in the modified version.  If I look at the working copy the formula looks like this.

=VLOOKUP($C$1,'Client Rates'!$A$2:J$228,5,FALSE)

As you can see it has quote marks in the table_array parameter because it does have a space in it.  However I cannot enter it this way as it throws an error every time I try.  Error is something like this - 'There is a problem with this formula. Not trying to type a formula? ... '

How can I enter the work sheet as a parameter with spaces in the name into the formula?

Comment: Okay I figured out if I open the VBA editor I can get the actual name of the sheet which fixed the problem when I refer to it by SHEET(nn) number.

Comment: Now I just need to find a way to edit and replace in all formulas affected.

Comment: I figured out that the problem that I was having had to do with the fact that I was copying _ctrl-c_ and pasting _ctrl-v_ from one workbook to another.  When I copied and pasted first to notepad and then from notepad all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to copy and paste directly from on workbook to another.  Copying ctrl-c and pasting ctrl-v from one workbook to another may not have the desired effect. If you copy first to notepad or some other text editor and then paste from that text editor all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try F2 to edit formula directly. Then highlight section of formula you wish to change then select the actual data you want evaluated by the formula?
Excel will create the correct string for the sheet and area reference for you.

Comment: Be sure the sheet names are indeed the same in both versions of workbooks.

Comment: Using F2 might work if I actually knew what to highlight.  As this is a copy of another workbook and I know very little about it I am trying to replace the literal worksheet reference in quotes with one that actually works.  The fact that the quoted reference works in the original but not in the copy is a bit confusing but not actually worth my time to further investigate.

Comment: I am still not sure why the following formula fails in one workbook but not the other.  =VLOOKUP($C$1,'Client Rates'!$A$2:J$228,5,FALSE)

Comment: Are both workbooks of the same version. IE is one *.xls and the other *.xlsm or some such? Just a thought.